# How to remove duplicates from linked list which repeats double number of times?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to create own linked list class on C++. My task is remove all nodes which data repeats double number of times in list and store only one node if data repeats odd number of times. I've written function removeDuplicates(), but my program crashes when i try to use the function. Implementation here:

```
void LinkedList::removeDuplicates(){
    Node *ptr1, *ptr2, *dup, *toDel;
    int counter = 1;
    ptr1 = top;
    while(ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL){
        ptr2 = ptr1;
        while(ptr2->next != NULL){
            if(ptr1->name == ptr2->next->name){
                dup = ptr2->next;
                ptr2->next = ptr2->next->next;
                delete dup;
                counter++;
            } else {
               ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            }
        }
        if(counter % 2 == 0){
            toDel = ptr1;
            ptr1->next = ptr1->next->next;
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
            delete toDel;
        }else{
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: how do you mean "double number of times"?
Also you declare some pointers to Node objects, and then use them without initialization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In modern C++, you do not need to explicitly initialize plain-old-datatypes to 0 (or NULL in this case). That is handled by the compiler according the standard precisely because of this class of bug. Regardless, all pointers in the above code are initialized prior to use.

Comment: Would you happen to have a cite that specifies that, @JimPri. To my understanding this is only true for statically-scoped objects, which always had zero-initialization. Just to be sure, with gcc 8.3 in -std=c++17 mode, which is as modern as it gets, compiling a simple test program into assembly with `-S`, and examining the results, does not seem to suggest that. The pointers are not initialized. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @JimPri it is bad practice and it depends on the specification. When you say 'modern', it doesn't mean that everyone is using c++17.
On the second look it seems all the variables are initialized before use.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: Please learn to use a debugger. Knowing the exact line where it crashes and looking at the variables and pointers at runtime, and stepping through the code will save you from asking these: "I wrote some code, it's broke, fix it please." 'questions'.
If [gdb](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/summary.html) is unwieldy for you, use visual studio or something.

As Some programmer dude suggested: [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Regarding your actual problem:

After your inner loop.

```
ptr1->next = ptr1->next->next;
```

is not checked `if (ptr1->next == NULL)`. Thus accessing `ptr1->next->next` will result in an access violation.

While that check is in the outer while loop condition, the inner while loop may delete and unlink the object from your list.

I'm also fairly certain that you want to reset your `counter` somewhere in the outer loop, probably right at the start. as it is now, it doesn't count the number of occurences of any one `ptr2->name`

Also you should initialize variables right in the declaration, it's just good style and may avoid further hassle.
It is also a good idea to set your pointers to NULL after deleting, so you DO get a nice null pointer exception instead of it randomly 'working' or crashing.